# Start a daemon thread that's a private method of the class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm new to C++11 threading and I'm trying to do something as follows:

```
class Something {
public:
    void start() {
        this->task_ = std::thread(&Something::someTask, this);
        this->isRunning_ = true;
        this->task_.detach(); // I read detach will stop it from hanging
    }

    void stop() {
        this->isRunning = false;
    }

    ~Something() {
         this->stop();
    }        

private:
    std::atomic<bool> isRunning_;
    std::thread task_;
    void someTask()
    {
        while(this->isRunning_) {
            // do something forever
        }
    }
};

Something whatever;
whatever.start();
```

However, the thread keeps getting blocked. Like nothing after `whatever.start()` executes. It just hangs while the loop runs.

Comment: Put this line `this->isRunning_ = true;` above `this->task_ = std::thread(&Something::someTask, this);`. Otherwise the thread loop might end before you set the condition to let it run.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. The loop is now exiting instantly for some reason.

Comment: Just voted to close this. Obvious reason making it off-topic is that it lacks the complete but minimal code to reproduce the issue. Further, the topic is misleading, an obvious race-condition was found but subsequently ignored and there is too much interpretation (as opposed to observation) in the text. In summary, this isn't a useful entry to anyone else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The usual pattern to do this is

```
class Something {
public:
    void start() {
        this->task_ = std::thread(&Something::someTask, this);
        // this->task_.detach(); <<<<<< Don't do that.
    }

    void stop() {
        this->isRunning_ = false;
        task_.join(); // <<<  Instead of detaching the thread, join() it.
    }

    ~Something() {
         this->stop();
    }        

private:
    std::atomic<bool> isRunning_;
    std::thread task_;
    void someTask()
    {
        this->isRunning_ = true;
        while(this->isRunning_) {
            // do something forever
        }
    }
};
```

---

Detaching a `std::thread` usually isn't a good idea, unless there's some kind of synchronization set up, that allows to wait for the thread execution to end before the process ends as a whole.

---

[*Demonizing*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html) a process usually is realized with a `fork()` to create a background child process, and leave the parent process to return control to the caller.

Comment: I implemented that and now it's throwing "terminate called without an active exception".

Comment: My bad, it works, I forgot to add the "join()" to the destructor, thanks a lot

Comment: Setting isRunning to true in the run method is a recipe for a race condition. This should be done in start before starting the thread.

Comment: @Voo Why should this be a race condition? `isRunning_` is an `atomic<bool>`, you noticed that?

Comment: @πάντα if it weren't, it'd be UB and not just a race condition. The problem is that it's possible for stop() to be executed before isRunning is set to true by the thread function, in which case the stop signal would be lost although start had already been called.

Comment: You have `isRunning_` in `someTask()` and `isRunning` in `stop()`. Is this a typo or some special syntax?

Comment: @gen It was a typo. I fixed that THX.

Answer (score 2):

I recently wrote a generic class that does just this

```
#include<functional>
#include<thread>

//do action asynchronously until condition is false
class do_async_until{
public:
    do_async_until(std::function<void(void)> action,
                   std::function<bool(void)> condition);
    ~do_async_until();
    void start();
    void stop();
private:
    void _do();
    std::thread _worker;
    std::function<void(void)> _action;
    std::function<bool(void)> _condition;
};
//implementation
do_async_until::do_async_until(std::function<void(void)> action,
               std::function<bool(void)> condition):_action(action),
                                     _condition(condition){
}
do_async_until::~do_async_until(){
    stop();
}
void do_async_until::start(){
    _worker = std::thread(std::bind(&do_async_until::_do,this));
}
void do_async_until::stop(){
    if(_worker.joinable()){
        _worker.join();
    }
}
void do_async_until::_do(){
    while (_condition())
    {
        _action();
    }
}
```

this will run any function with the signiture void(void) until the condition function bool(void) returns true

example usage:

```
int main(int agrc,char** argv){
    bool running = true;
    auto do_this = [](){
        std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl;
    };
    auto condition = [&](){
        return running;
    };
    do_async_until async(do_this,condition);
    async.start();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    running=false;

    return 0;
}
```

The example should print "hello world" a bunch of times for one seconds then exit.

EDIT: to make this work with a member function you simply need to have an instance of do_async_until inside you class and pass the member function to the constructor of do_async_until using `std::bind(&foo::func,this)`

Comment: What's the difference to `async` and `future` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future)?

Comment: To the best of my understanding std::async is not good for a use case where the spawned thread will persist for a longer period of time. std::async seems to be best suited for one off computations where as I believe my design is closer to a persistent worker thread. std::async could theoretically be used to achieve the same result, but std::async does not make promises as to if the task will actually be completed on another thread or in place even if you specify std::launch::async. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async

Comment: As far as I can see the sample is broken - running has to be std::atomic for this to not invoke UB.

Comment: how so? what UB would result? only one thread is writing to running and only one thread is reading running. even if that is the case it is an easy fix to make

Comment: Unsequenced reading and writing to a non atomic variable is UB.

Comment: Understood, like i said though that should be an easy fix